# C++ Multithreading crashes application

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, thread-safety

I am trying to get 2 threads running, one takes a screenshot and changes the global image variable, the other one reads the image and detects objects.
Everything works fine when im using a std::mutex to lock the image like the following:

Thread1

```
void mHandler()
{
    while (true) {
      mat_img_mutex.lock();
      mat_img = hwnd2mat(); //screenshot is taken and saved into global mat_img
      mat_img_mutex.unlock();
      Sleep(3);
   }
}
```

Thread2

```
mat_img_mutex.lock();
result_vec = detector.detect(mat_img); //image detection
mat_img_mutex.unlock();
```

So far so good, but this doesn't really help me because its blocking each others thread execution so it doesn't have any performance advantage over just using one thread.

**What i tried:**
Thread1, taking the screenshot function out of the mutex lock so only the variable definition happens in the mutex. This CRASHES the program though and i have no idea why.

```
void mHandler()
{
    while (true) {
      cv::Mat img_copy = hwnd2mat(); //heavy screenshot function out of the mutex
      mat_img_mutex.lock();
      mat_img = img_copy //screenshot is taken and saved into global mat_img
      mat_img_mutex.unlock();
      Sleep(3);
   }
}
```

Thread2, i also tried taking the detection function out of the mutex with the same idea which resulted in a crash as well which is weird as i thought the copy instructor of c++ inst referencing the variable what so ever so it shouldn't have any problems with simultaneous read/writes...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167725/discussion-on-question-by-cross-wade-c-multithreading-crashes-application).

Answer (score 0):

cv::Mat uses reference counting. Make sure to get a copy of the data. Use

```
mat_img = img_copy.clone()
```

to get a deep copy of the image.